# Detect screenshots taken ON ANY APP within my iOS app

Tags: ios, screenshot, background-process

Is it possible to detect when the user takes a screenshot **in any app** while my app is in the background ? And how would I do that ?

If not, can I background check regularly for screenshots (not pictures from the camera) in the photo library ? Like every minute or hour ?

Comment: No I an pretty sure iOS makes this Impossible

Comment: @OptimusCrime I do think it's difficult but I want to be sure it can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get your app to detect Screenshots is:

1. Register with the Photo Library's PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver
2. When your app receives a notification that a photo has been added,
   check its PHAssetMediaSubtype
3. If the Subtype is PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot, you know a new
   Screenshot has been taken.

> The PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver protocol notifies you of changes that
>   occur in the Photos library, regardless of whether those changes are
>   made by your app, by a user in the Photos app, or by another app that
>   uses the Photos framework.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phphotolibrarychangeobserver

Comment: How do you skip screenshots which are taken while your own app is active?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov by removing the observers when app goes in background.